# Trying to deploy my application on render.com, trying connecting to db via internal url, connection is getting refused, app trying a local connection

Tags: node.js, deployment, redis, node-redis, connection-refused

I'm trying deploying my application wherein im using workers and ques for jobs, trying to connect the redis instance to my application , connection is getting refused. I thik app still trying to hit a local connection.
Here is my redis.js in config

```
const redis = require('redis');

// Redis configuration options
const redisConfig = {
  url: 'redis://red-cjds7cavvtos73bpvvn0:6379',
  host: 'red-cjds7cavvtos73bpvvn0'
};
console.log('redis config started with redis url: ',redisConfig.url)
// Create a Redis client
const client = redis.createClient(redisConfig);
console.log("client added: ",client)
// Event listeners for Redis client
client.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('Connected to Redis');
});

client.on('error', (error) => {
  console.error('Error connecting to Redis:', error);
});
console.log('exporting the connection')

// Export the Redis client
module.exports = client;
```

following is  my import of the config file in server's root index

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
const redisConnection=require('./config/redis')
const path = require('path')
const port = 7000
const db = require('./config/mongoose')
```

following is the error in the deployement logs on render:

```
==> Using Node version 14.17.0 (default)
Aug 19 04:40:37 AM  ==> Docs on specifying a Node version: https://render.com/docs/node-version
Aug 19 04:40:37 AM  ==> Starting service with 'node index.js'
Aug 19 04:40:43 AM  redis config started with redis url:  redis://red-cjds7cavvtos73bpvvn0:6379
Aug 19 04:40:43 AM  client added:  Commander {
Aug 19 04:40:43 AM    _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
Aug 19 04:40:43 AM    _eventsCount: 0,
Aug 19 04:40:43 AM    _maxListeners: undefined,
Aug 19 04:40:43 AM    commandOptions: [Function: commandOptions],
Aug 19 04:40:43 AM    select: [AsyncFunction: SELECT],
Aug 19 04:40:43 AM    subscribe: [Function: SUBSCRIBE],
Aug 19 04:40:43 AM    unsubscribe: [Function: UNSUBSCRIBE],
Aug 19 04:40:43 AM    pSubscribe: [Function: PSUBSCRIBE],
Aug 19 04:40:43 AM    pUnsubscribe: [Function: PUNSUBSCRIBE],
Aug 19 04:40:43 AM    sSubscribe: [Function: SSUBSCRIBE],
Aug 19 04:40:43 AM    sUnsubscribe: [Function: SUNSUBSCRIBE],
Aug 19 04:40:43 AM    quit: [Function: QUIT],
Aug 19 04:40:43 AM    multi: [Function: MULTI],
Aug 19 04:40:43 AM    bf: {},
Aug 19 04:40:43 AM    cms: {},
Aug 19 04:40:43 AM    cf: {},
Aug 19 04:40:43 AM    tDigest: {},
Aug 19 04:40:43 AM    topK: {},
Aug 19 04:40:43 AM    graph: {},
Aug 19 04:40:43 AM    json: {},
Aug 19 04:40:43 AM    ft: {},
Aug 19 04:40:43 AM    ts: {},
Aug 19 04:40:43 AM    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
Aug 19 04:40:43 AM  }
Aug 19 04:40:43 AM  exporting the connection
Aug 19 04:40:48 AM  server is ua and running on port: 7000
Aug 19 04:40:48 AM  events.js:353
Aug 19 04:40:48 AM        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
Aug 19 04:40:48 AM        ^
Aug 19 04:40:48 AM  
Aug 19 04:40:48 AM  Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
Aug 19 04:40:48 AM      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16)
Aug 19 04:40:48 AM  Emitted 'error' event on Queue instance at:
Aug 19 04:40:48 AM      at RedisClient.<anonymous> (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/kue/lib/redis.js:65:13)
Aug 19 04:40:48 AM      at RedisClient.emit (events.js:376:20)
Aug 19 04:40:48 AM      at RedisClient.on_error (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/kue/node_modules/redis/index.js:401:14)
Aug 19 04:40:48 AM      at Socket.<anonymous> (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/kue/node_modules/redis/index.js:279:14)
Aug 19 04:40:48 AM      at Socket.emit (events.js:376:20)
Aug 19 04:40:48 AM      at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
Aug 19 04:40:48 AM      at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
Aug 19 04:40:48 AM      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
Aug 19 04:40:48 AM    errno: -111,
Aug 19 04:40:48 AM    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
Aug 19 04:40:48 AM    syscall: 'connect',
Aug 19 04:40:48 AM    address: '127.0.0.1',
Aug 19 04:40:48 AM    port: 6379
Aug 19 04:40:48 AM  }
```

please help!

I tried adding host to the connection configurations but still it's not connecting correcly please help me establish the redis connection